# Get html url var

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using the code bellow to send a variable to another page but i got "undefined"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.letterz').click(function () {
var selectedletter = $(this).attr("id");
$("#celebdetails").load("reveal.html?surname="+selectedletter, function() {
$('.myloader').fadeOut("fast");
$('#celebdetails').fadeIn("slow");
});
});

});
</script>
```

**my html**

```
<div class="myloader"></div>

<div id="#celebdetails" style="display:none;"></div>

<div class="letterz" id="A"></div>
<div class="letterz" id="B"></div>
<div class="letterz" id="C"></div>
<div class="letterz" id="D"></div>
```

And in the second page that i am sending the parameter surname i am using the code below to fetch it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var me = getUrlVars()["surname"];   
alert(me);

});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What gives you: `console.log(vars);` ???

Comment: I might be wrong but your getUrlVars function is called after it is loaded in the calling page (the first page) and that is why `getUrlVars()["surname"]` is undefined

Comment: @A.Wolff gives me: Uncaught ReferenceError: vars is not defined

Comment: alot of post in stackoverflow got the answer. this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @IreneT. but how you are checking for it? Put code just before returning it from function. BTW, why calling your variable as it is hash part of URL, that's not hash you are looking for, but that's just a misspelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with This :

```
function geturlvar() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
 }
```

Call it like :

```
 var as = geturlvar()['urlvar'];
```

So URL : `http://stackoverflow.com?result=202`

then : `var myvar = geturlvar()['result'];`

```
myvar contains : 202;
```

Comment: i am still getting undefined... :-(

Comment: So check your URL is it contain your passed variable ? @lrene

Comment: if i put an alert when i am pressing a letter it appears the id.. that means that clickable div with id gets the id var.. the second page doesn't grab it..